# aws amplify authenticator UI does not hide after login

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I've setup a basic app with login for a POC, but when I login successfully via Google, the login screen stays, only if I refresh the entire page then it goes away.

Do I have to hide Authenticator manually? I thought it should handle this on its own.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    { path: "/", element: <Navigate to="/user"/> },
    { path: "/logged-out", element: <LoggedOut/> },
    {
        path: "/user",
        element: <Layout><Dashboard/></Layout>,
        children: [
            { path: "dashboard", element: <Layout><Dashboard/></Layout> },
            { path: "bookings", element: <Layout><Bookings/></Layout> },
            ]
    },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
    <Authenticator socialProviders={['apple', 'facebook', 'google']}>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <RouterProvider router={router} fallbackElement="put some spinner component here like <SuperSpinner/>"/>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Authenticator>
);
```